# Sharing an archived iOS build won't succeed on the clients side - no such file or directory

Tags: xcode, ios, code-signing

For one of my clients, I've developed a small iOS app. I'm a member of their dev team, so I've been using a development certificate to sign my local test builds.

Now the app is almost done and it should go into internal testing on the clients side. I created an archived build of the app which I then sent to my client. They imported it into the organizer and tried to "Share" it to be able to re-sign it using an ad hoc profile.

Creating the .ipa fails with an "no such file or directory" error though. The archive appears to be fine otherwise - the organizer shows all the usual information, the icon, and it will let them export it as another archive. Creating an .ipa without re-signing fails as well, which leads me to believe this is not an issue with ther certs and provisioning profile.

If I try the same thing on my side, writing an .ipa from the very same archive using my development cert, the operation succeeds.

It may be worth mentioning that the same procedure was working fine while we were still using XCode 3.x on earlier projects. This is the first time we've been trying this using XCode 4.

No additional (static) libraries have been used.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

**Edit:**

Someone at the apple dev forums suggested to me that I should check the system console for xcode error messages while attempting to export the .ipa - none were printed out. We discovered some other, older messages however, which read as follows:

> 18.04.11 13:54:35 /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode[123] /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-04-15/Foobar.xcarchive/dSYMs/Foobar.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist:
>   set flags (was: 00200000): Operation
>   not permitted

The timestamp is roughly at the time when my client first imported my archive, but we can't be sure since we didn't watch the console back then.

The message had been printed multiple time, once for every single ressource file contained in the bundle. Does this tell you guys something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

Following another suggestion on the apple dev forum, we repaired permissions on both systems. Additionally, I built and archived the app again and used a different way to transmit the archive to my client. We did all of this in one try, so I can't quite tell which of these measures actually did the trick. If you stumble across this because you have the same problem, you might want to try all of this, too.

Thanks for listening!

**Update:**

It happened again - and this time, we tried to solve it step by step. Result: It's all about how the file is being transmitted. I just attached the archive package to a mail to my client, that's what broke it, although I don't know why. Zipping the archive before transmitting it solved the problem, however.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading XCode 4.3 beta with the IOS 5 SDK, the Organizer function to share and archive stopped working with a cryptic error "No such file or directory found".
It turns out that this is related to having two different versions of codesign_allocate . To fix the problem, do the following in a terminal window.

sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin

Another hint - try the manual way to create a shared ipa - since it gives you a lot more detail of what went wrong. See http://blog.dmahajan.net

Can you see if this is also linked to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

EasyCoder's answer fixed this issue for me - I have the 5.0 beta SDK and had the same problem.

I ran the following and it was fixed:

ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin/codesign_allocate